# Knockout Component View Not Updating When Its ViewModel Observable Changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a component setup to use AMD to get the html template and viewmodel code. Everything works fine. The component loads when it is supposed to and behaves fine with the params passed to it. The problem is I defined an observable in the viewModel whose value shows up in the template view, but when the observable's value changes the text on the view does NOT change. Can anyone explain what is going on here? The text I am trying to bind to is modalTitle. When the modal loads its title is 'TEMP' but if I go to the console and type 'window.modalTitle()' I get 'CREATE REPORT SCHEDULE'. It's like the view is getting the first value of the observable and then ignoring it after that. Is there anyway I can force it to look for updates?

ViewModel: (schedules.component.js)

```
  define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
  console.log('schedules hit');
  loadCss('schedules');

  function SchedulesViewModel(params) {
    this.scheduledItems = params.scheduledItems;
    this.itemName = params.itemName;
    this.modalTitle = ko.observable("TEMP");
    window.modalTitle = this.modalTitle;
  }

  SchedulesViewModel.prototype.initiateAddScheduledItem = function () {
    this.modalTitle("CREATE " + this.itemName + " SCHEDULE");
    $('#schedulesModal').modal('show');
  };

  SchedulesViewModel.prototype.removeSelectedScheduledItem = function () {
    this.chosenValue('dislike');
  };

  window.ReportsApp.SchedulesViewModel = SchedulesViewModel;

  return SchedulesViewModel;
});
```

View Template

```
<div id="schedulesModal" class="modal fade lcmsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>-->
        <img src="/Content/images/modalASLogo.png" style="float: right;" />
        <h4 class="modal-title" data-bind="text: modalTitle()">Test Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body ...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- /Bootstrap Modal -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not get changed because `this.itemName` has not been defined as an observable. it is better to define a computed observable which will automatically update whenever any observables change.

Instead of using `prototype` to add methods, you can use knockout function which foes it for you.
Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/34/

```
 function SchedulesViewModel(params) {
    var self = this ;
    self.scheduledItems = ko.observable(params.scheduledItems);
    self.itemName = ko.observable(params.itemName);
    self.modalTitle = ko.observable("TEMP");
    self.chosenValue= ko.observable();

   self.modalTitle = ko.computed(function() {
        return "CREATE " + self.itemName() + " SCHEDULE" ;
    }, self);

    // you can change below to show your modal whenever you want
    $('#schedulesModal').modal('show');

    self.removeSelectedScheduledItem = function (){
        self.chosenValue('dislike');
    }
  }


ko.applyBindings(new SchedulesViewModel({scheduledItems:"scheduledItems" ,itemName : "itemName" }));
```

**Update** : yes you can have multiple view models or better to say nested view models. Look at the new example and see how you can communicate between your models.https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/35/

Comment: Wow, very good eye there - I didn't even notice that my observable was dependent on a non-observable. I think working with async components threw me off - I usually declare the entire view model as an IIFE which to me allows better encapsulation but with an async module you explicitly need to return a regular function for it to work.

The only question I have that I will have to look at later is making a second call to ko.applyBindinds as seen here. Since this is just a component I have a normal viewModel that the component inherits from. I don't know if you can have multiple viewModels.

Comment: I understand the jsfiddle and nested viewModels so I guess my question would be: can I call applyBindings as many times as I want? Remember that the code above is for an asynchronously loaded component and we will have many of them. I already have the global viewModel saved to a window variable, but when the second component loads, how will it get the viewModel from the first component so all components viewmodels are bound? I can't seem to bind these component's viewModels to the global context. window.schedulesViewModel = SchedulesViewModel does not work. Neither does saving the passed ko.

Comment: You need to define an observable variable inside your global ViewModel for any subviewModels you want to have an access through entire your website. In fact whenever you want to load any subviewModel you create a new instance of the subview model and assign it to your global viewModel's observable variable.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give it a shot! I actually love this idea because I think it solves my other problem: I currently cannot find a way to view the components ViewModel properties in the console. Since my global ViewModel is already assigned to window.AppName.ViewModel, adding an observableArray of component ViewModels should allow us to be able to see ALL the properties in all the ViewModels from the console, where we also make changes to observables and observe how it plays out on the page in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work. When I try calling ko.applyBindings on my component's dom element I get a 'You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element' error. This means that Knockout automatically creates a ViewModel via the component registration process and binds to the component's element - I did some debugging against the ko code to verify this. Sadly I can't find a way to bind this mysteriously created ViewModel to the window element for debugging AND it also doesn't seem to work. I'll ask a new question on SO with these new issues brought up. Thanks again.